# How to prevent a missing, unused annotation class from crashing my program?

Tags: android, exception, classloader

I want to use a class from a 3rd party library which is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` from `javax.xml.bind.annotation`. This annotation does not exist on Android and is prohibitively hard to add (as it is in a protected namespace).

I actually don't use the class in a JAXB context, so I'm more than happy to ignore the annotation. The Android JVM however is not and throws a `ClassNotFounException` from the classloader:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/csiro.truststore.client.tssandroidclient-2.apk]
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoad
```

Is there any way to get Android to ignore the annotation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way of ignoring it but [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) will remove annotations during obfuscation. You usually wouldn't obfuscate a development build but you could possibly configure the obfuscation process to ignore all classes and thus only remove annotations.

Comment: Thanks, good lead. Something that works for development build would be preferred though :-).